# Codeigniter how to get an id from current selected record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this **package** table:

```
+----+--------------+
| id | package_name |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | simple       |
|  2 | elegant      |
+----+--------------+
```

and this **brochure** table:

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | package_id |    image    |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 |          1 | simple.jpg  |
|  2 |          2 | elegant.jpg |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

And then I looped the **package table** record to generated list for tab like so:

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#package_1" data-toggle="tab">
        Simple                
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#package_2" data-toggle="tab">
        Elegant                
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="package_1">
      <div class="col-xs-3" id="package-detail">            

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-7" id="brochure_1">
        <!-- SHOW BROCHURE IMAGE BY PACKAGE ID HERE -->

        <!-- END -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane " id="package_2">
      <div class="col-xs-3" id="package-detail">

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-7" id="brochure_2">
        <!-- SHOW BROCHURE IMAGE BY PACKAGE ID HERE -->

        <!-- END -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want tho display ***image*** from **brochure table** based on ***id*** from **package table** triggered by selected tab list and put the image between this tag:

```
<div class="col-xs-7" id="brochure_2">
  <!-- SHOW BROCHURE IMAGE BY PACKAGE ID HERE -->

  <!-- END -->
</div>
```

and this is my controller

```
$this->load->model('admin/package_model', 'package');
// SELECT ALL DATA FROM PACKAGE TABLE
$this->data['packages'] = $this->package->get();

$this->load->model('admin/brochure_model', 'brochure');
// GET DATA FROM BROCHURE TABLE WHERE PACKAGE_ID = ID (FROM PACKAGE TABLE FROM     SELECTED TAB)
$this->data['brochures'] = $this->brochure->get_by(array(
  'package_id' => ID VARIABEL FROM SELECTED TABS'
));

$this->load->view('frontend/page/package', $this->data);
```

Thank you before

Comment: so you can get data on view why you want query on view?

Comment: send your id to controller and fetch data and send fetched data to view

Comment: create a function who get records by giving id and add a js function to <a href="#package_1" data-toggle="tab" onclick="getimage(id);"> then make a js function and post id(ajax) to your function which getting data and show your response using ajax

Comment: so need to use ajax for this

Comment: You should make a join query where u select both tables.